# Fire jquery event from Java

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

I have few elements generated dynamically with a jQuery click event on each element defined as follows:

```
$(".addToCart").live("click", function(e) {
 <!-- function body goes here -->
});
```

Now I need to implement button that adds all elements like if used clicked on each one of them. I have implemented all logic in a servlet but now after I click the "Add all" button I need to refresh the page to get the UI refreshed.
I wonder if I can fire a jQuery event from servlet in order to update GUI.

Comment: You can't (in the general case); Java is on the server, jQuery is on the client. Why wouldn't you have a button that fires the events implemented in JavaScript?

Comment: "Fire a jQuery event from Servlet (Java)" is not possible. Java is server-side, jQuery runs on client side. However, could you show some more of your relevant code and give more details? Maybe we are able to find a workaround. As it is currently written, I do not know exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @DaveNewton I think he'd like to update the cart on the server side

Comment: @Powerslave What the events do isn't really relevant; whatever triggers the event needs to live on the client.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yes, but that's what makes invoking the server side necessary. I still think using AJAX would be the perfect solution here (e.g. JSON-RPC); then, the UI could be updated by JS/jQuery based on the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to update the UI within the Javascript. Java and JQuery are to separate beasts and you cannot call functions between them. E.g. Java cannot call javascript, javascript cannot call Java.

Instead you should add a JQuery function to "add all" similar to the one you have shown:

```
$(".addAll").live("click", function(e) {

    <!-- Send AJAX request to tell the server that the user has added all items to the cart -->L
    <!-- If there are no errors, update UI to reflect the add all button being pressed -->
});
```

If you need the function to update something server side, then that function will need to make an AJAX call to tell the server what has been added to the cart. See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to javascript and after reading your answer I found out that I just need to iterate over all elements inside some <div> tag and pass them to click handle function. Can you gime me an example how I can do that?